# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable - I can't find solution

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scr.py", line 18, in <module>
    for title in link.find('a'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

And the lines are these:

```
for each in soup.find_all(attrs={'class' : 'table table-bordered table-custom'}):
    for link in each.find_all('td'):
        for title in link.find('a'):
            print "\033[1;37m%s" % title.text
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Falta um paramêtro."

else:
    data = requests.get("http://theanonybay.org/search?q=%s" % sys.argv[1].replace(" ", "%20")).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    for each in soup.find_all(attrs={'class' : 'table table-bordered table-custom'}):
        for link in each.find_all('td'):
            for title in link.find('a'):
                print "\033[1;37m%s" % title.text

            for little in link.find_all(attrs={'class' : 'btn btn-flat btn-xs btn-warning'}):
                print "Magnet Link:\033[0;37m", little.get('href'),"\n\n"
```

Comment: please stop using soup because python has improved since then

Answer (score 3):

You are using `link.find()`, which always returns either an element *or `None` if the element isn't found*.

It means there is no `a` link in the current `td` cell. You probably shouldn't loop over the link object *anyway* even if it is found, because then you are looping over the contents of the  element.

You'd have to explicitly test if anything was found first:

```
a_element = link.find('a')
if a_element:
    # not None, so we can proceed
    ...
```

If you wanted to find all link texts in a given table, it is usually easier to use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead; start with each row, then drill down from there to get the links:

```
for row in soup.select('.table-custom tr'):
    link = row.find('a', text=True)
    if link:
        print "\033[1;37m%s" % link.get_text(strip=True)
    for magnet in row.select('a[href^=magnet:]'):
        print "Magnet Link:\033[0;37m", magnet['href']
    print
```

Note that rather than manually escape the query for the search, leave escaping to `requests` by using the `params` argument. You should use the `response.content` attribute instead and leave decoding to BeautifulSoup; servers often don't include a content characterset in the headers and then requests is forced to assume Latin-1 was used, and that is most often wrong:

```
params = {'q': sys.argv[1]}
response = requests.get("http://theanonybay.org/search", params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
```